# Can I omit the $and in the $match stage in Mongo's aggregate?

Tags: mongodb

In $match, is there a difference in behaviour between the following with and without $and?

```
db.emails.aggregate([
  {
    $match : {
      $and: [
        {receivedAt: { $gte: "2021-01-01"}},
        {receivedAt: { $lt: "2022-02-01" }}
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

or

```
db.emails.aggregate([
  {
    $match : {
      receivedAt: {
        $gte: "2021-01-01",
        $lt: "2022-02-01"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can avoid explicit `and`. By default, its `and`.

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions.

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)

But, Refer [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#behavior) where you may need explicit `and`